# Converting date from database to angular format

Tags: angularjs, date, format

I'm unable to parse date in angularjs, where date is coming from database and instead of showing correct date which is in database, it is showing me '0001-01-01T00:00:00'.Do I need to convert it? Is there any way in angular that convert the date.?

Comment: in which format do you get the date from the database? and how are you trying to parse it? some code plz

Comment: it is in date format getting from sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'0001-01-01T00:00:00' is a unix format (ISO 8601 or another). This format is natively supported by javascript.

If you want to convert it in a readable date, do :

```
var myDate = new Date('0001-01-01T00:00:00')
```

Comment: Sort out the problem.. Thanks benek

Comment: You're welcome. Do not hesitate to check my answer if it is the right one :)